# Azure cache 2.2 works but 2.3.x doesnt

Tags: caching, azure

I have an azure project with a dedicated cache role for session.  With azure cache 2.2 and lower it works just fine but when I upgrade it fails with the following error.  I downgrade and it works again.

> [SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
>   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResultNoResult.EndInvoke()
>   +217    Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannelFactory.TcpConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result) +163
>
> [DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a
>   temporary failure. Please retry later....
>   Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with
>   the server: net.tcp://CacheWorkerRole:24233

The error doesn't seem to lead to anything that has worked.

Ideas?

Web config

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="CacheWorkerRole" />
   </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>

 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="SessionProvider">
      <providers>                        
        <add name="SessionProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" applicationName="MIS" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that your cloud service is using SDK Version 2.3. Based on the Nuget Package page here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/, this version of caching will only work with Azure SDK Version 2.3.

[image]

Comment: oh my gosh,  I can't believe i missed something so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: How do we check what version the Azure service is using? I cannot find that in the Azure Portal.